# Qt threading stopped UI from responding

Tags: multithreading, qt

I think I might misunderstood several concepts in Qt's threading,

In my window class, which is derived from QWidget:

```
class Widget 
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Widget::Widget (QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
   {
     moveToThread(&th); // still stuck
     connect (&th, SIGNAL(started()), SLOT(doWork())); 
     th.start();
   }
private:
   QThread th;
private slots:
  void doWork () 
  { 
     // hmm, this stuck the UI
     while (1) 
     { 
       qDebug() << "Sleeping"; 
     } 
  };
};
```

The forever loop stuck the UI, it shouldn't be, since that was called by the QThread.
Can anyone point out what's wrong about this code?

Comment: I'm not an expert of QThreads but aren't you supposed to subclass QThread and have your work in the run method? Your custom widget would then run the thread in its constructor and I think it wouldn't be blocking (haven't tried it thought).

Comment: Shouldn't you subclass QThread and put the content of doWork inside its run() method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Widget::dowork()` is executed on the main thread (on which the GUI runs), that's why it blocks. It doesn't matter that it was called by a QThread.

The correct way to execute code on another thread is to first move a QObject instance to a QThread using `QObject::moveToThread()`, and then connect the `started()` signal of the QThread to the slot of the QObject instance that you want executed.

If you want to know more: https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong

Another issue with your code is that you're trying to move a QWidget-derived object to another thread. This is not allowed. QWidget instances must remain on the main thread. Instead, you should subclass from QObject.

Yet another issue with the code is that you're doing this in the constructor. Moving the object to another thread while it's not fully constructed yet is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Really weird! A lot of people telling me not to subclass QThread, but subclass + moveToThread is the right way! Otherwise it wouldn't work

Comment: @warl0ck Those people are right, but you should also note that the only thread that may contain QWidget delivered classes is main thread. You can moveToThread all classes that don't belong to QtGui module