# cannot emit from defined thread to main UI thread

Tags: qt, qt4

emits included in customized thread inside my program does not work. it seems my thread has no communication with the main UI thread. in c# we have thread dispatcher to handle this. what about QT?

this runs inside thread:

```
void myThread::run(){

    while(1)
    {
        //do something
        emit display("show the result");  //NOT WORKING, THOUGH CONNECTED
    }
}
```

myThread xx;
xx.start();

Comment: Can you please post some code? How signals/slots defined, connect/emit code.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you seem to be using QThread wrong. A QThread has an event loop, and in your case, that event loop is blocked in your run() function.

What you should be doing instead is implement a QObject where you put the code you want to run, then create a vanilla QThread and use QObject::moveToThread() to move your QObject to that thread. Then you can send and receive signals normally since the QThread's event loop is not blocked.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13142366/856199