# A slot gets called in the middle of QThread::run

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I am modifying a multithreaded Qt application and have faced an unforeseen behaviour.

I have a class WorkerThread inherited from QThread with method `run()` in it doing some work. A slot `handleSuccess()` of an object of WorkerThread is connected to a signal from another — main thread, the signal is emitted in response to asynchronous ingoing connections from a server. As I understand, while `run()` is running an flow control is not in `exec()` of an event loop, the slot cannot be called. Instead, I see in logs of app that the thread is doing its work in the middle point of `run()` and then instantly enters the slot without doing any preparations.

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WorkerThread() { moveToThread(this); /* further initialization */ }
    void run();
    void foo();

public slots:
    void handleSuccess(const QByteArray &);
    void shutdown();

private:
    QMutex mutex;
    MyResource resource;
    volatile bool mShutdown;

/* ... other declarations */
};

void WorkerThread::foo() {
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    /* Working with the guarded resource */
}

void WorkerThread::run() {
    QEventLoop signalWaiterEventLoop;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(terminated()), &signalWaiterEventLoop, SLOT(quit()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(shutdownThread()), &signalWaiterEventLoop, SLOT(quit()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(dbChanged()), &signalWaiterEventLoop, SLOT(quit()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    while (!mShutdown) {
        signalWaiterEventLoop.exec();
        if (mShutdown) break;
        /* ... useful payload */
        foo();
        /* ... another payload */
    }
}


void WorkerThread::handleSuccess(const QByteArray & data) {
            log(Q_FUNC_INFO, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    /* processing data */
}

void WorkerThread::shutdown()
{
    mShutdown = true;
    emit shutdownThread();
}
```

The object is created and initialized in the main thread:

```
void SomeClass::init() {
    /* ... */
    mWorker = new WorkerThread();
    connect(connect(mProtocol, SIGNAL(dataReceived(QByteArray)), mWorker, SLOT(processSuccess(QByteArray)),
                Qt::QueuedConnection));    
    mWorker->start();
    /* ... */
}
```

The error occurs when `foo()` gets called from inside `run()`, locks the mutex, and then the flow control is passed to `handleSuccess()` without any reason visible to me, and, at last, `handleSuccess()` tries to lock the mutex resulting in a deadlock. I would stress that all this happens in a single thread, I've logged that. The fact is, the error is stable, arises every time in the same place. It's clear that I do not take something into account, but what exactly?

**Update**
I have rewritten the `WorkerThread` into `Worker: public QObject` and the former `run()` became public slot `handleNewArrivals()`, which is called in the thread's event loop in response to signals. Still, the problem remains: another slot is executed right in the middle of `handleNewArrivals()`. The place of interruption is stable, here it is (seek `evaluateTo()`):

```
    bool hasContent = false;
    QByteArray outData;
    QBuffer inputBuffer(&data), outputBuffer(&outData);
    inputBuffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    outputBuffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Append);

    QXmlQuery xmlQuery;
    xmlQuery.bindVariable("inputDocument", &inputBuffer);
    xmlQuery.setQuery("doc($inputDocument)/commands//*");

    QXmlSerializer serializer(xmlQuery, &outputBuffer);
    log(Q_FUNC_INFO, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    // the log line above appears, then after 1 ms the line
    // from handleSuccess() appears successively.
    xmlQuery.evaluateTo(&serializer);

    // this line is never shown
    log(Q_FUNC_INFO, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(outData);
    while (!xmlReader.atEnd()) {
        xmlReader.readNext();
        if (xmlReader.tokenType() == QXmlStreamReader::Invalid) {
            ufo::logT(this) << tr("Invalid token: %1").arg(xmlReader.errorString());
            continue;
        }

        if (!xmlReader.isStartDocument() && !xmlReader.isEndDocument()) {
            xmlWriterDb.writeCurrentToken(xmlReader);
            hasContent = true;
        }
    }
    ufo::logT(this) << tr("Selected data from payment, hasContent = %1").arg(hasContent?"true":"false");
    inputBuffer.close();
    outputBuffer.close();
```

What can be with QXmlQuery::evaluateTo and QXmlSerializer to cause such jump? It seems like there is an exception or unix-like signal (the software runs under Windows, mingw32) or something, though wrapping `evaluateto()` or the whole body of slot in try-catch gives nothing.

Comment: No time for a full answer right now, but I suspect that subclassing QThread and overriding run() is not the correct threading model for your case, but you instead should be using QThread as a handle to a thread and not place your code directly in it. This will give you correct event dispatching and you won't need the kludgy approach of firing up your own custom event loop. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13142366/856199

Comment: You're not showing us real code in at least one place (which might be important).  Your `connect()` to the worker object looks like `connect(connect(mProtocol, SIGNAL(dataReceived(QByteArray)), mWorker, SLOT(processSuccess(QByteArray)),Qt::QueuedConnection));` which has at least two problems - a nested `connect()` call and there is no slot named `processSuccess()`.

Comment: Right, the double connect is a mistype, and the slot is `handleSuccess`:
    connect(mProtocol, SIGNAL(dataReceived(QByteArray)), mWorker, SLOT(handleSuccess(QByteArray)),
                Qt::QueuedConnection)); 
I am not sure I have the right to post the real code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you're being bitten by this bit of behavior [documented for `QXmlQuery`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qxmlquery.html#event-handling):

> Event Handling
>
> When QXmlQuery accesses resources (e.g., calling fn:doc() to load a
>   file, or accessing a device via a bound variable), the event loop is
>   used, which means events will be processed. To avoid processing events
>   when QXmlQuery accesses resources, create your QXmlQuery instance in a
>   separate thread.

If a `dataReceived()` signal has been queued for the `handleSuccess()` slot, when `QXmlQuery` uses the event loop the event will be processed.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, it looks exactly like what I get. I have to make make a workaround.

Comment: Everything worked exellently after I moved QXmlQuery and the related calls into another thread.

Answer (score 0):

All `QThread` objects are created in GUI thread and belong to it. That's why any slots defined in a QThread-derived class will be executed in the main GUI thread, not in the thread the object represents.

If you want this slot to execute in the other thread, the simpliest solution would be to move `WorkerThread` object to this thread using `moveToThread(this)`.

This is however not the best decision. Considering the code you have posted, I see no reason why you should subclass QThread. The default QThread implementation already fulfill your needs. You should remove WorkerThread class, create another QObject-derived class e.g. WorkerObject, then move it to new thread using `QObject::moveToThread`. After that any slots of this object will be executed in another thread.

Comment: I'll try to separate WorkerThread's logic out to non-QThread class, but I'm still do not know why the slot is called so intrusively and, hence, I'm not sure that this behaviour will not repeat itself.

Comment: `run()` is executed in the thread WorkerThread represents. `handleSuccess` is executed in the main thread. That's why they can be called simultaneously at any time.

Comment: They are called from the same thread, i.e. with the same thread id. That is why I get a deadlock. If the mutex was ackquired from within different threads, the second thread would be simply waiting for the first a bit. In fact, execution is never returned to `run` even if I comment out the whole body of `handleSuccess` and hence never lock  the mutex inside. It seem like some exception, but wrapping run() in try-catch shows no catches.

Comment: It appears to me that you have created new QEventLoop and called its `exec()` method. So your new event loop is calling your slots. Calling slots is what QEventLoop do. It's not surprising. Why do you need to create new event loop at all? You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Above, Michael Burr suggested the place where the event loop is implicitly run.